# how can i implements web view in ionic-vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

i want to make an hybrid app that shows website pages in mobile device and i also need to

implements some native functionality like push notifications in this app

i already have complete source codes that is made with html , css, javascript and jsp

so i want to use this codes

but it is not easy for me to find guideline to implement webview in ionic-vue

how can i make an hybrid app in Ionic-vue Framework that shows webpage in mobile device

i try to consult https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser this documentations

but since i am a begginer , it is not easy for me to understand

and is it possible to implements pushnotifications and file upload and download from webview to moblie device ?

here is App.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-router-outlet />
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script>
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    IonApp,
    IonRouterOutlet
  }
});
</script>


here is Tab.vue

<template>
    <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
      
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
       
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
<script>
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';

export default  {
  name: 'WebViewer',
  
  created (){
  
     Browser.open({ url: 'https://devchannel.co.kr/' })
  }
  
}
</script>
```